# Large-scale system management

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm looking to upgrading a system that is becoming a bit cumbersome once I get over a few hundred PCs.

I've been googling this for a bit now, but I can't seem to find many options that do kiosk-lockdown, management, remote-desktop, file transfer other than signagelive and sitekiosk.

Are there any other technologies out there that I could leverage that I'm not finding?

Comment: Shouldn't this go to ServerFault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified what OS the PC's are running, but here are my favorite tools for both Windows and Linux

- [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com) - Configuration Management
- [GoToAssist](http://www.gotoassist.com/remote-support/) - Remote Login, file transfer
- [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com)  - Remote Login, file transfer
- [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com) - Remote Login, file transfer
- [Fog](http://www.fogproject.org)    - Provisioning
- [Katelloo](http://www.katello.org) - Provisioning, Package Management,
- [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org)  - Distributed orchestration
- [Serf](http://www.serfdom.io)     - Distributed orchestration
- [MCollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective) - Distributed orchestration

If these machines are dumb kiosks, you may find doing a diskless 'thin pc' much easier to manage. Or reimage with fog on a regular basis (say every night)

- [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/virtualization/thinpc.aspx)
- [Vmware](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2276890)
- [Citrix](http://www.citrix.com/products/xendesktop/overview.html) <- This may be your best match.

**Update1**

Checkout boxstarter for windows pc's

https://boxstarter.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm using windows, but if the right tool can do all that in Linux, I'd consider saving on license fees

Comment: also I should mention, this is more of a kiosk application, where a machine can be far away on an unknown network. SiteKiosk/Remote has had that advantage that as long as the ports are not blocked, vnc connection happened easily because all connections were outbound.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, however it depends on your skill set and underlying willingness to support open source software.

If you are familiar with Linux then I would strongly suggest that you look into the [Linux Terminal Server Project](http://www.ltsp.org/), plus using [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.org/) for deployment and ldap for user management as this would fit all of your requirements.

Plus as a side note, its very easy to launch this up using Raspberry Pis

Comment: There is a youtube vid on how to do this with Raspberry Pis at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcq5rWEeDko